# Regex: Match a string value in JSON array, split string into multiple values

Tags: arrays, regex, json, string

[Tool: Sublime Text 3]

Hello I'm looking for some help with regex, I have very little experience with it so I'm hoping for some help.

I plan to use the regex to help me replace my json file with lots of data in it (over 6k LOC).

I'm looking for a regex that **matches the string inside an array** in the following json, and split those results (seen in *End result*):

```
["Cleric, Ritual Caster, Wizard"]
```

End result:

```
["Cleric", "Ritual Caster", "Wizard"]
```

List of classes (don't know if it would help in the regex): **Bard, Cleric, Druid, Paladin, Ranger, Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard**

*Edit: I forgot to add what tool I'm using, using Sublime Text 3 atm, but I can use JavaScript to rewrite the new data and copypasta over my current json file.

Removed invalid json, I'm only looking to edit/fix the array.

Comment: which tool/lang you're running?

Comment: `"class": ["Ritual Caster"]` is it absolute or  `"class": [any single entry]`?

Comment: What programming language do you use? Is it Java?

Comment: Don't process JSON with regexps.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3, trying to replace data in a json file

Comment: I am not familiar with this language, but I can tell general steps to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Check the first string in the class property (which is assumedly an array) for a comma.
if (characterStats['class'][0].indexOf(',')) {
    // Reassign the property to the result of splitting this string at every comma. If the array has anything beyond the 0th entry, this will remove it.
    characterStats['class'] = yourBlob['class'][0].split(',')
}
```

Edit:

So we're checking the first entry in the array, which in your example was a big string with multiple commas. We're checking it for the indexOf a comma. If a comma exists in the string (and is past the 0th index), then we will reassign the `.class` property of your object to the string which is newly split into an array at each comma.

This solution addresses the data model:

```
{
    class: ['one,big,string,of,words']
}
```

and turns it into:

```
{
    class: ['one','big','string','of','words']
}
```

This solution assumes that you will never have something like this:

```
{
    class: ['wizard', 'sorcerer, cleric, knave']
}
```

In which case, you'll have to do some fancier looping and checking.

Answer (score 1):

In JS you could do:

```
var classInput = ["Cleric, Ritual Caster, Wizard"];
var classString = classInput[0];  // get the String from the Array
var classOutput = classString.split(/,\s/g); // split into and Array with separate strings
```

Or shorter:

```
var classInput = ["Cleric, Ritual Caster, Wizard"];
var classOutput = classInput[0].split(/,\s/g);
```

example with your list of classes:
http://jsfiddle.net/bbmh1a5v/4/

P.S. "class" is often a special word in computer languages, like "id","var" and many more - if possible, try to avoid using "class" as key-word. Better try "characterClass", "profession", ...

Comment: Umm, why would you replace `,\s` first and then split on commas, instead of just splitting on `/,\s/` to start with? With regard to your comment about `class`, I guess you mean using it as a property name, not a "key-word", but actually, there's no problem in modern browsers with using `class` as a property name.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion: you're right - the regex can be used directkly in split - updated my answer